# Change field separator with awk or sed of a specific set of columns

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to modify a file where both tabs and spaces are used as field separators.
At the beginning we have a file with this type of structure:

```
 chr1    Cufflinks    gene_id "XLOC_000001"; oId "XR_003076322.1";
 chr1    Cufflinks    gene_id "XLOC_000012"; oId "XR_001548508";
```

Doing `awk -F' ' '$4=$6 {print $0}'` performs what I am looking for (changing the value of the "gene_id" by the value in "oId"):

```
 chr1 Cufflinks gene_id "XR_003076322.1"; oId "XR_003076322.1";
 chr1 Cufflinks gene_id "XR_001548508"; oId "XR_001548508";
```

The problem is that it changes the line structure: the tabs `\t` between `chr1`, `Cufflinks` and  `gene_id` disappeared. I tried adding `-v OFS=\t` but it puts tabs in the `gene_id "XLOC_000012"; oId "XR_001548508";` part (which should stay separated by spaces). I also tried with `sed` something like `sed -i 's/ /\t/'` but it also put tabs everywhere.

How could I change the field separator of column 1 to 3 (and do not change columns 3 to 6) ?

Comment: Your condition `$4=$6` is NOT actually a condition, `=` is an assignment operator, so are you looking to compare $4 and $6? or you want to assign 4th field value as 6th field? Kindly confirm it once.

Comment: No, it's not a condition, it's on purpose. I need to assign the $6 value to $4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility with awk:

```sh
awk -F '[ ]' '{$2 = $4; print}' file
```

By using the space character for the input field separator (as opposed to spaces and tabs), a field can be assigned to without changing the tab characters to spaces.

For more complex cases, there is `split` (but no "`join`"):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {n = split($3, a, " "); a[2] = a[4]; for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    $3 = (i == 1 ? "" : $3 " ") a[i]
} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed` that preserves your whitespaces:

```sh
sed -E $'s/^([ \t]*([^ \t]+[ \t]+){3})[^ \t]+([ \t]+)(([^ \t]+[ \t]+){1})([^ \t]+)/\\1\\6\\3\\4\\6/' ff
```

```
chr1    Cufflinks    gene_id "XR_003076322.1"; oId "XR_003076322.1";
chr1    Cufflinks    gene_id "XR_001548508"; oId "XR_001548508";
```

**Explanation for copying 6th field to 4th field:**

- `^`:                           # match start
- `([ \t]*([^ \t]+[ \t]+){3})`:  # match first 4-1 fields and capture in group #1
- `[^ \t]+`:                     # match 4th field
- `([ \t]+)`:                    # match whitespace after 4th field and capture in group #3
- `(([^ \t]+[ \t]+){1})`:        # match next (6-4-1) fields and capture in group #4
- `([^ \t]+)`:                   # match 6th field and capture in group #6
- `\\1\\6\\3\\4\\6`: Place back-reference back in substitution

---

Alternatively this `awk` also creates a tabular aligned output:

```sh
awk '$4=$6' file | column -t

chr1  Cufflinks  gene_id  "XR_003076322.1";  oId  "XR_003076322.1";
chr1  Cufflinks  gene_id  "XR_001548508";    oId  "XR_001548508";
```

Comment: Thanks, the first answer is correct but not the second one as it puts tab everywhere. Could you explain the sed command please ? I would need to adapt this to a more complex file with more than 15 columns like these

Comment: I will add explanation in my `sed` command. Yes second will not preserve original  whitespaces but it will create new tabular format.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these explanations :) It works fine